# RAM drive for compiling - is there such a thing?

Tags: caching, compilation, directory, ramdrive

<s>[An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354160/what-do-you-do-while-your-codes-compiling#354176)</s> **(see below)** to one of the questions right here on Stack Overflow gave me an idea for a great little piece of software that could be invaluable to coders everywhere.

I'm imagining RAM drive software, but with one crucial difference - it would mirror a real folder on my hard drive. More specifically - the folder which contains the project I'm currently working on. This way any builds would be nearly instantaneous (or at least a couple orders of magnitude faster). The RAM drive would synchronize its contents with the hard disk drive in background using only idle resources.

A quick Google search revealed nothing, but perhaps I just don't know how to Google. Perhaps someone knows of such a software? Preferably free, but reasonable fees might be OK too.

**Added:** Some solutions have been suggested which I discarded in the very beginning. They would be (in no particular order):

- **Buy a faster hard disk drive ([SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) maybe or 10K RPM).** I don't want a hardware solution. Not only software has the potential to be cheaper (freeware, anyone?), but it can also be used in environments where hardware modifications would be unwelcome if not impossible - say, at the office.
- **Let OS/HDD do the caching - it knows better how to use your free RAM.** The OS/HDD have generic cache algorithms that cache everything and try to predict which data will be most needed in the future. They have no idea that for me the priority is my project folder. And as we all know quite well - they don't really cache it much anyway. ;)
- **There are plenty of RAM drives around; use one of those.** Sorry, that would be reckless. I need my data to be synchronized back to the HDD whenever there is a bit of free time. In the case of a power failure I could bear losing the last five minutes of work, but not everything since my last checkin.

**Added 2:** An idea that came up - use a normal RAM drive plus a background folder synchronizer (but I do mean **background**). Is there any such thing?

**Added 3:** Interesting. I just tried out a simple RAM drive at work. The rebuild time drops from ~14 secs to ~7 secs (not bad), but incremental build is still at ~5 secs - just like on the HDD. Any ideas why? It uses `aspnet_compiler` and `aspnet_merge`. Perhaps they do something with other temp files elsewhere?

**Added 4:** Oh, nice new set of answers! :) OK, I've got a bit more info for all you naysayers. :)

One of the main reasons for this idea is not the above-mentioned software (14 secs build time), but another one that I didn't have access at the time. This other application has a 100 MB code base, and its full build takes about 5 minutes. Ah yes, it's in [Delphi 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi), so the compiler isn't too advanced. :) Putting the source on a RAM drive resulted in a BIG difference. I got it below a minute, I think. I haven't measured. So for all those who say that the OS can cache stuff better - I'd beg to differ.

**Related Question:**

> [RAM disk for speed up IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501718/ram-disk-for-speed-up-ide)

**Note on first link:**
The question to which it links has been deleted because it was a duplicate. It asked:

> What do you do while your code’s compiling?

And the answer by [Dmitri Nesteruk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9476/dmitri-nesteruk) to which I linked was:

> I compile almost instantly. Partly due to my projects being small, partly due to the use of RAM disks.

Comment: Why is hardware modification impossible in the office?  We always have some budget available, if the value is there.  Also, I've been known to buy hardware with my own money, just to make my work experience more pleasant.

Comment: In my case the builds take ~15s incremental and ~30s full. Not really something to convice the boss with. But it would be nice if it were 1s. :) And I don't want to invest my own money in this. Besides - there are many people out there and each has a different story. Many might have use of this too.

Comment: If I was your boss, I'd be interested in ways to get your build time down from 15s/30s to 1s.  *Any* perceivable delay is an opportunity for improvement.  Developer productivity is directly impacted by any delay.

Comment: @Jay unfortunately in many companies equipment and engineering time are completely different costs according to the accounting structure, and it often sadly makes financial sense to go cheap on the hardware even with the huge extra expense of the engineering time.  Boss may not have control over it.

Comment: the link to the answer in the very beginning does not work, could you update it?

Comment: It is pretty unbelievable how many people take a "the OS cache so don't bother" or "use an SSD" stance to this sort of thing, without benchmarking.

I just finished setting up a new build server for myself, the build server already has an SSD. I added a ramdisk to the process which reduces the build time from 12 to 10 minutes for one platform, as the system needs to build for 3 platforms thats a ~6 minute reduction overall.

Of course on a build server theres no need to worry about syncing anything back except the results, so is a bit easier to set up.

Answer (score 22):

In Linux (you never mentioned which OS you're on, so this *could* be relevant) you can create block devices from RAM and mount them like any other block device (that is, a HDD).

You can then create scripts that copy to and from that drive on start-up / shutdown, as well as periodically.

For example, you could set it up so you had `~/code` and `~/code-real`. Your RAM block gets mounted at `~/code` on startup, and then everything from `~/code-real` (which is on your standard hard drive) gets copied over. On shutdown everything would be copied ([rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)'d would be faster) back from `~/code` to `~/code-real`. You would also probably want that script to run periodically, so you didn't lose much work in the event of a power failure, etc.

I don't do this anymore (I used it for [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) when the 9.5 beta was slow, no need anymore).

[Here is how to create a RAM disk in Linux.](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html)

Comment: +1 - Put the script in cron to rsync every five minutes or so, and nice it so it doesn't kill performance. I don't know how this would be accomplished on Windows, but there is a task scheduler, and there are rsync tools, so those plus a RAM disk app should work for you if that's your platform.

Comment: Yap, I use Windows. Vista Business 32-bit, to be precise. :) But other OS are relevant to the topic too. And, yes - the idea to use simple ramdisk+folder sync utility (xcopy in the most simple case) has already crossed my mind. See above.

Answer (score 16):

I'm surprised at how many people suggest that the OS can do a better job at figuring out your caching needs than you can in this specialized case.  While I didn't do this for compiling, I did do it for similar processes and I ended up using a RAM disk with scripts that automated the synchronization.

In this case, I think I'd go with a modern source control system. At every compile it would check in the source code (along an experimental branch if needed) automatically so that every compile would result in the data being saved off.

To start development, start the RAM disk and pull the current base line.  Do the editing, compile, edit, compile, etc. - all the while the edits are being saved for you.

Do the final check in when happy, and you don't even have to involve your regular hard disk drive.

But there are background synchronizers that will automate things - the issue is that they won't be optimized for programming either and may need to do full directory and file scans occasionally to catch changes. A source code control system is designed for exactly this purpose, so it would likely be lower overhead even though it exists in your build setup.

Keep in mind that a background sync task, in the case of a power outage, is undefined. You would end up having to figure out what was saved and what wasn't saved if things went wrong. With a defined save point (at each compile, or forced by hand) you'd have a pretty good idea that it was at least in a state where you thought you could compile it. Use a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) and you can easily compare it to the previous code and see what changes you've applied already.

Comment: Keeping the source files on ramdisk is dangerous - better to keep them on disk and have automated sync'ing to the ramdisk before builds. +1 for OS not always handling specialized needs perfectly, though!

Comment: The source files are used and edited on ramdisk, but I'm suggesting that at every compile they are saved off to regular disk or repository.  I'm not suggesting using a ramdisk alone with no form of non-volatile saving.

Answer (score 8):

See *[Speeding up emerge with tmpfs](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Speeding_up_emerge_with_tmpfs)* ([Gentoo Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentoo_Linux) wiki).

Speeding up compiles using RAM drives under Gentoo was the subject of a how-to written many eons ago. It provides a concrete example of what has been done. The gist is that all source and build intermediate file are redirected to a RAM disk for compile, while final binaries are directed to the hard drive for install.

Also, I recommend exploring maintaining your source on hard drive, but `git push` your latest source changes to a clone respository that resides on the RAM disk. Compile the clone. Use your favorite script to copy the binaries created.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Use https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ramdisk to make the RAM disk.

Then I wrote these scripts to move directories to and from the RAM disk. Backup is made in a [tar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) file before moving into the RAM disk. The benefit of doing it this way is that the path stays the same, so all your configuration files don't need to change. When you are done, use `uramdir` to bring back to disk.

Edit: Added C code that will run any command it is given on an interval in background. I am sending it `tar` with `--update` to update the archive if any changes.

I believe this general-purpose solution beats making a unique solution to something very simple. KISS

**Make sure you change path to rdbackupd**

#### ramdir

```
#!/bin/bash

# May need some error checking for bad input.

# Convert relative path to absolute
# /bin/pwd gets real path without symbolic link on my system and pwd
# keeps symbolic link. You may need to change it to suit your needs.
somedir=`cd $1; /bin/pwd`;
somedirparent=`dirname $somedir`

# Backup directory
/bin/tar cf $somedir.tar $somedir

# Copy, tried move like https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ramdisk
# suggests, but I got an error.
mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk$somedir
/bin/cp -r  $somedir /mnt/ramdisk$somedirparent

# Remove  directory
/bin/rm -r $somedir

# Create symbolic link. It needs to be in parent of given folder.
/bin/ln -s /mnt/ramdisk$somedir $somedirparent

#Run updater
~/bin/rdbackupd "/bin/tar -uf $somedir.tar $somedir" &
```

#### uramdir

```
#!/bin/bash

#Convert relative path to absolute
#somepath would probably make more sense
# pwd and not /bin/pwd so we get a symbolic path.
somedir=`cd $1; pwd`;

# Remove symbolic link
rm $somedir

# Copy dir back
/bin/cp -r /mnt/ramdisk$somedir $somedir

# Remove from ramdisk
/bin/rm -r /mnt/ramdisk$somedir

# Stop
killall rdbackupd
```

rdbackupd.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

struct itimerval it;
char* command;

void update_archive(int sig)
{
    system(command);
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    it.it_value.tv_sec     = 1;   // Start right now
    it.it_value.tv_usec    = 0;
    it.it_interval.tv_sec  = 60;  // Run every 60 seconds
    it.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("rdbackupd: Need command to run\n");
        return 1;
    }
    command = argv[1];

    signal(SIGALRM, update_archive);
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &it, NULL); // Start

    while(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this only synchronizes to the HDD when you explicitly tell it to, NOT in the background, right?

Comment: Also should be able to mount as directory with ntfs on atleast windows nt4 and batch files

Comment: @Vilx- Added C code that will run in background and update the tar file if there are any changes to the files. Can specify interval in C code.  Making it take time as a parameter is trivial.  Does everything you need now.

Comment: Will kill all the backup processes when uramdir. Can be addressed.

Comment: Well, crond is just as fine, and I think it would be more efficient than `while(true);` ;) Anyways, this fails on one account still - "uses only idle resources". If it kicks in while I'm compiling, it'll be noticeable. But still, thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 3):

We used to do this years ago for a [4GL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth-generation_programming_language) macro-compiler; if you put the macro library and support libraries and your code on a RAM disk, compiling an application (on an 80286) would go from 20 minutes to 30 seconds.

Comment: That's all nice and fine - there are plenty classical RAMDrives around. But I don't want my code to live SOLELY on the RamDrive. That's a bit dangerous you know. ;) I would like it to be synchronized to HDD whenever there is a bit of free time to do so.

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe - set in Scheduled Tasks to run every minute? Now THAT would kill my PC's performance. :P Although I suppose I could make it copy only newer files. Still it's pretty much work.

However you did give me an idea - maybe some background folder synchronizator?

Comment: @Vlix: in our scenario, it took about 2 seconds to copy the files to the RAM disk before compiling, and 2 seconds to copy them out after compiling. I think some RAM disk products offer a shadow/synch feature

Answer (score 3):

I don't have exactly what you're looking for, but I'm now using a combination of [Ramdisk](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/05/27/free-ramdisk-for-windows-vista-xp-2000-and-2003-server/) and [DRAM ramdisk](http://www.acard.com.tw/english/fb01-product.jsp?prod_no=ANS-9010&type1_title=%20Solid%20State%20Drive&idno_no=270). Since this is Windows, I have a hard 3 GB limit for core memory, meaning I cannot use too much memory for a RAM disk. 4 GB extra on the 9010 really rocks it. I let my IDE store all its temporary stuff on the solid state RAM disk and also the [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) repository. The DRAM RAM disk has a battery backup to the flash card. This sounds like an advertisement, but it really is an excellent setup.

The DRAM disk has double SATA-300 ports and comes out with 0.0 ms average seek on most tests ;) Something for the Christmas stocking?

Comment: Sweet, but I don't have that much spare money. Plus, as I said - I want it to be software.

Comment: This sounds really cool (though not meeting the posters criteria). Does the backup to flash happen automatically whenever the drive is powered down, or what?

Comment: Yep. The battery is enough to persist dram to the flash card. And it happens when mains power is lost.

Comment: The sad thing about these solutions is that the several GB/s of dram is limited to the SATA-300 interface speeds :(

Comment: At least it's dual SATA-300 interface ;) Strangely enough, I don't feel sad about it....

Answer (score 3):

Yep, I've met the same problem. And after fruitless googling I just wrote a Windows Service for lazy backing up the RAM drive (actually - any folder, because RAM drive can be mounted in to, for example, the desktop).

http://bitbucket.org/xkip/transparentbackup
You can specify interval for full scan (default 5 minutes).
And an interval for scanning only notified files (default 30 seconds).
Scan detects changed files using the 'archive' attribute (the OS resets that one specially for archiving purpose). Only files modified that way are backed up.

The service leaves a special marker file to make sure that target backup is exactly a backup of the source. If the source is empty and does not contain a marker file, the service performs automatic restore from backup. So, you can easily destroy the RAM drive and create it again with automatic data restoration. It is better to use a RAM drive that is able to create a partition on system start up to make it work transparently.

Another solution that I've recently detected is [SuperSpeed SuperCache](http://www.superspeed.com/desktop/supercache.php).

This company also has a RAM disk, but that is another software. SuperCache allows you use extra RAM for block-level caching (it is very different from file caching), and another option - mirror you drive to RAM completely. In any scenario you can specify how often to drop dirty blocks back to the hard disk drive, making writes like on the RAM drive, but the mirror scenario also makes reads like from the RAM drive. You can create a small partition, for example, 2 GB (using Windows) and map the entire partition to RAM.

One interesting and very useful thing about that solution - you can change caching and mirroring options any time just instantly with two clicks. For example, if you want your 2 GB back for gamimg or virtual machine - you can just stop mirroring instantly and release memory back. Even opened file handles does not break - the partition continues to work, but as a usual drive.

EDIT: I also highly recommend you move the TEMP folder to te RAM drive, because compilers usually make a lot of work with temp. In my case it gave me another 30% of compilation speed.

Answer (score 2):

Your OS will cache things in memory as it works.  A RAM disk might seem faster, but that's because you aren't factoring in the "copy to RAMDisk" and "copy from RAMDisk" times.  Dedicating RAM to a fixed size ramdisk just reduces the memory available for caching.  The OS knows better what needs to be in RAM.

Comment: This is true if you're copying the stuff to and from RAM every compile, but the idea is that you're copying to ram once, and compiling several times after making minor changes.  I've done this before for related processes (not compiling) and for huge data sets is makes a really big difference.

Comment: Don't trust the caching strategy of the OS to give you the same performance as your own caching strategy.

Comment: Shouldn't the contents of recently accessed or modified files, i.e., those touched by the compiler, be in the file system cache?

Comment: read-caching is only part of the problem, compiling produces output files - possibly with suboptimal write patterns, and often a bunch of temporary files.

Comment: I feel like compiling tools flush files to disk, like permanent databases. So, the file may be catched but flushing it nevertheless takes Disk access time and am not sure but tools seem waiting until flushing completes. You need to disable durability instead of enabling caching. But you seems right in practice. My experiment shows that there is no performance difference besides the disk thrashing, which does not affect the performance figures.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Profile.**  Make sure you do good measurements of each option. You can even buy things you've already rejected, measure them, and return them, so you know you're working from good data.
2. **Get a lot of RAM.** 2 GB DIMMs are very cheap; 4 GB DIMMs are a little over US$100/ea, but that's still not a lot of money compared to what computer parts cost just a few years ago. Whether you end up with a RAM disk or just letting the OS do its thing, this will help. If you're running 32-bit Windows, you'll need to switch to 64-bit to make use of anything over 3 GB or so.
3. **Live Mesh** can synchronize from your local RAM drive to the cloud or to another computer, giving you an up-to-date backup.
4. **Move just compiler outputs.** Keep your source code on the real physical disk, but direct .obj, .dll, and .exe files to be created on the RAM drive.
5. **Consider a [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control).**  Clone from the real drive to a new repository on the RAM drive. "push" your changes back to the parent often, say every time all your tests pass.

Comment: 2. Not true.  If your hardware supports PAE the OS can address more than 4G, just each application's address space is limited to 4G.

Comment: @Adam> only for server editions of Windows - client editions limit you to 4GB of address space (yes, AS, not physical memory! mix of market segmentation and "3rd parties wrote buggy drivers" excuse).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same idea and did some research. I found the following tools that do what you are looking for:

- [VSuite RAM disk](http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/vsuite-ramdisk/)
- [DiskBoost](http://www.everstrike.com/ramdisk/)

However, the second one I couldn't manage to get working on 64-bit Windows 7 at all, and it doesn't seem to be maintained at the moment.

The VSuite RAM disk on the other hands works very well. Unfortunately I couldn't measure any significant performance boost compared to the [SSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) disc in place.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could build something like a software RAID 1 where you have a physical disk/partition as a member, and a chunk of RAM as a member.

I bet with a bit of tweaking and some really weird configuration one could get Linux to do this.  I am not convinced that it would be worth the effort though.

Answer (score 1):

What can be super beneficial on even a single-core machine is parallel make. Disk [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) is a pretty large factor in the build process.  Spawning two compiler instances per CPU core can actually increase performance.  As one compiler instance blocks on I/O the other one can usually jump into the CPU intensive part of compiling.

You need to make sure you've got the RAM to support this (shouldn't be a problem on a modern workstation), otherwise you'll end up swapping and that defeats the purpose.

On [GNU make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29#Derivatives) you can just use `-j[n]` where `[n]` is the number of simultaneous processes to spawn. Make sure you have your dependency tree right before trying it though or the results can be unpredictable.

Another tool that's really useful (in the parallel make fashion) is [distcc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distcc). It works a treat with GCC (if you can use GCC or something with a similar command line interface). distcc actually breaks up the compile task by pretending to be the compiler and spawning tasks on remote servers. You call it in the same way as you'd call GCC, and you take advantage of make's -j[n] option to call many distcc processes.

At one of my previous jobs we had a fairly intensive Linux operating system build that was performed almost daily for a while. Adding in a couple of dedicated build machines and putting distcc on a few workstations to accept compile jobs allowed us to bring build times down from a half a day to under 60 minutes for a complete OS + userspace build.

There's a lot of other tools to speed compiles existing. You might want to investigate more than creating RAM disks; something which looks like it will have very little gain since the OS is doing disk caching with RAM. OS designers spend a lot of time getting caching right for most workloads; they are (collectively) smarter than you, so I wouldn't like to try and do better than them.

If you chew up RAM for RAM disk, the OS has less working RAM to cache data and to run your code -> you'll end up with more swapping and worse disk performance than otherwise (note: you should profile this option before completely discarding it).

Answer (score 1):

> There are plenty RAMDrives around, use one of those. Sorry, that would be reckless.

Only if you work entirely in the RAM disc, which is silly..

Psuedo-ish shell script, ramMake:

```
# setup locations
$ramdrive = /Volumes/ramspace
$project = $HOME/code/someproject

# ..create ram drive..

# sync project directory to RAM drive
rsync -av $project $ramdrive

# build
cd $ramdrive
make

#optional, copy the built data to the project directory:
rsync $ramdrive/build $project/build
```

That said, your compiler can possibly do this with no additional scripts.. Just change your build output location to a RAM disc, for example in Xcode, it's under Preferences, Building, "Place Build Products in:" and "Place Intermediate Build Files in:".

Answer (score 1):

My final solution to the problem is vmtouch: https://hoytech.com/vmtouch/
This tool locks the current folder into (ram) cache and vmtouch daemonizes into background.

```
sudo vmtouch -d -L ./
```

Put this in shell rc for fast access:

```
alias cacheThis = 'sudo vmtouch -d -L ./'
```

I searched for a ready made script for quite a while, because I didn't want to waste a lot of time on writing my own ramdisk-rsync-script. I'm sure I would have missed some edge cases, which would be quite unpleasant if important code was involved. And I never liked the polling approach.

Vmtouch seems like the perfect solution. In addition it doesn't waste memory like a fixed size ramdisk does.
I didn't do a benchmark, because 90% of my 1Gig source+build folder were already cached, but at least it feels faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like disk caching which your operating system and / or your hard drive will handle for you automatically (to varying degrees of performance, admittedly).

My advice is, if you don't like the speed of your drive, buy a high speed drive purely for compiling purposes.  Less labor on your part and you might have the solution to your compiling woes.

Since this question was originally asked, spinning hard disks have become miserable tortoises when compared to SSDs.  They are very close to the originally requested RAM disk in a SKU that you can purchase from Newegg or Amazon.

Comment: Unfortunately OS/HDD don't let me tell them "cache this folder at all costs". :)

And I was looking for a software solution instead of hardware because my office PC has enough RAM but I'm not sure my employer would be happy if I started messing with the hardware. Plus, it could be free. ;)

Comment: I do agree. A RAM disk is an order of magnitude faster than a hard disk for certain purposes, and I'm tired of getting the same "no need for a RAM disk" answer each time I ask for one :-)

Comment: Okay, let's put it another way: this sounds like an optimization problem.  Exactly what speed problem are you trying to solve?  Compile time to actual disk or compile time to runnable binary?

Comment: Even a 10k rpm raptor/velociraptor drive didn't bring *that* great compile-time reductions over a decent 7200rpm drive for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas off the top of my head:

Use Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) (not [Process Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Explorer)) to check what goes on during a build - this will let you see if `%temp%` is used, for instance (keep in mind that response files are probably created with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY which should prevent disk writes if possible, though). I've moved my `%TEMP%` to a RAM disk, and that gives me minor speedups in general.

Get a RAM disk that supports automatically loading/saving disk images, so you don't have to use boot scripts to do this. Sequential read/write of a single disk image is faster than syncing a lot of small files.

Place your often-used/large header files on the RAM disk, and override your compiler standard paths to use the RAM drive copies. It will likely not give *that* much of an improvement after first-time builds, though, as the OS caches the standard headers.

Keep your source files on your harddrive, and sync to the RAM disk - **not the other way around**. Check out [MirrorFolder](http://www.techsoftpl.com/backup/index.php) for doing realtime synchronization between folders - it achieves this via a filter driver, so only synchronizes what is necessary (and only does changes - a 4 KB write to a 2 GB file will only cause a 4 KB write to the target folder). Figure out how to make your [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) build from the RAM drive although the source files are on your harddisk... and keep in mind that you'll need a **large** RAM drive for large projects.

Answer (score 0):

The disk slowdown you incur is mainly write, and also possibly due to virus scanners. It can vary greatly between OSes too.

With the idea that writes are slowest, I would be tempted to setup a build where intermediate (for example, `.o` files) and binaries get output to a different location such as a RAM drive.

You could then link this bin/intermediate folder to faster media (using a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) or [NTFS junction point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point)).

Answer (score -2):

Just as James Curran says, the fact that most programs follow the law of locality of references, the frequent code and data page count will be narrowed over time to a manageable size by the OS disk cache.

RAM disks were useful when operating systems were built with limitations such as stupid caches (Win 3.x, Win 95, DOS). The RAM disk advantage is near zero and if you assign a lot of RAM it will suck memory available to the system cache manager, hurting overall system performance. The rule of thumb is: let your kernel to do that. This is the same as the "memory defragmentation" or "optimizers" programs: they actually force pages out of cache (so you get more RAM eventually), but causing the system to do a lot of page-faulting over time when your loaded programs begin to ask for code/data that was paged out.

So for more performance, get a fast disk I/O hardware subsystem, maybe RAID, faster CPU, better chipset (no VIA!), more physical RAM, etc.

Comment: RAM disks can still offer substantial advantages. 1) you're 100% guaranteed to be in ram, OS cache doesn't guarantee this. 2) FS metadatase journalling... 3) overzealous filesync (firefox profile on ramdrive can go a *lot* faster than on a regular disk - remember backups though :) ).

Comment: 1) For most applications, data not being 100% at RAM is a good thing, I think, due to (again) reference locality 2) This could be true, but for good FS journalling algorithms? [examples?] 3) I don't know, I'm sure you are using it to assert that :)