# Is this laptop good enough for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, hardware

For HP 2133 Mini:

- 1.2 Ghz CPU
- 1 GB RAM
- Windows XP
- 5400 RPM HDD

I'm planning to install Visual Studio 2005 (assuming it's faster than 2008). I've seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations question so I'll take those into the account.

But do you think Visual Studio 2005 is going to work in an acceptable speed with this hardware?

Comment: It won't be a pleasure, but you should be able to be productive...

Comment: VS2008 should actually be BETTER (faster/less memory) than VS2005 in my experience.

Comment: If VS2008 is faster that's even better for me :) I can ignore all C++ and TS crap, than I'll be just fine. Cheers for the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would be a bit sluggish when compiling, but otherwise should be OK. I'd suggest a bit more RAM though. It's cheap these days and upgrading from 1GB to 2GB will really have an effect, especially if you're also running other programs in the background.

Plus, then you might consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354254/ramdrive-for-compiling-is-there-such-a-thing).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you mean by *acceptable*. In my experience a 7200RPM hard drive will boost VS.NET 2005 performance speed as it is a very IO intensive application.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the kinds of projects you intend to work on on the laptop.  Visual Studio will certainly run just fine (2-4 GB of RAM would be better), but if you have large solutions you will see some performance degradation.  Also, acceptable speed is in the eye of the beholder.  It would probably drive me crazy, but others might be just fine with that machine.

Also, check out Scott's post here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/11/01/tip-trick-hard-drive-speed-and-visual-studio-performance.aspx

HTH

Colby Africa

Answer (score 2):

Scott Hanselman has a [good post about using netbooks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DellMini9PracticalDevelopersReview.aspx) for Visual Studio development. His post specifically covers the Dell mini, but a lot of what he says applies to other netbooks as well.

Answer (score 1):

That laptop is probably pushing the lower limit of "good enough". If you're writing a resource intensive app, it probably will be pretty slow when you're debugging. For a web site, you'll probably only slow down when the IDE is doing something intensive.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about screen size. Anything less than 14/15 (inches) is not going to be usable.

Comment: That's totally untrue... I have a 13.1" screen and I'm very productive.

Comment: If you hide all the things around the edges of the screen, it should be pretty OK. Fullscreen helps too.

Comment: @Jason - us oldies have trouble viewing 12 point font @ 1280x1024 with a 17, much less a 13 =)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this opinion, at least not enough to downvote it.  Also, I agree - the resolution you'd have to run to see enough lines on a 13" monitor would be unacceptable for daily use for me.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I would go for at least 2gb of RAM and a descent screen size, I agree with StingyJack and wont go for anything less than 15"

The requirements of VS 2005 is one thing, but keep in mind that you will probely use servel other applications at the same time.

My laptop has a 17" screen, it works but at times i still miss the 22" wide screen I use at work.

Answer (score 0):

add memory

as much as you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers, I'll add more RAM (as mentioned they are really cheap). I'm restricted with the monitor so it'll be 8.9 :)

The idea is I'll use this laptop do some presentation around, and If I need to debug or hack it on the way I should able to do it. There won't be any actual development other than, small hacks (hopefully!).

Answer (score 0):

a 4:3 ratio screen will be much better then a 16:9, you will have much more vertical space

Comment: I find 16:9 to be better for visual studio, it's easier to leave the project manager and other windows open on the side.